# Se me van los componentes del Frame cuando uso método place() en Tkinter

Tags: python

Estoy arrancando con tkinter y tengo este problema: cuando uso la función `place` se me va el componente ya sea un `label` o un `button`, etc, etc... no se muestra. Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal y si estoy implementando bien el uso de la biblioteca, muchas gracias abrazo.

> Archivo MainFrame.py

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    __buttonExit = None
    __label = None

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(0, 0)
        self.master.iconbitmap('src/Images/puzzle-piece.ico')
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack()
        
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.master.title('Main Frame')
        self.master.geometry('400x400')

        self.__label = tk.Label(self, text="Un Label")
        self.__label.place(x=10, y=30)
        self.__buttonExit = tk.Button(self, text='Salir', command=quit)
        self.__buttonExit.place(x=2, y=4)
```

> Archivo Main.py

```
from src.Frames.MainFrame import MainFrame
import tkinter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    frame = MainFrame(master=root)
    frame.mainloop()
```

Entonces al dar uso del place, los componentes no aparecen :c. Un saludo gente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta me gusto muchísimo. Tampoco entendía por que el `.place()` no funcionaba mientras que `pack()`y `grid()` si. Estuve investigando y llegue a tu solución [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409532/problems-with-place-in-gui-with-tkinter).

Lo que ocurre es que no le diste una medida al `frame` y tampoco estas usando el `geometry` para que crezca, este hace que por defecto su medida sea de 1x1. ¿Qué significa esto? Que el `button` y el `label` si están apareciendo solo que se encuentran dentro de un mísero pixel XD

### Aparentemente...

esto es uno de los grandes problemas de `place`, tienes que especificar un lugar y una medida explicita a todas las cosas para que aparezcan:)

### Tu código debería ser algo así:

> Main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = MainFrame(master=root)
    frame.config(width=480,height=320) #Esto es lo que te faltaba. 
    frame.mainloop()
```

p.d. esas son las medidas solo son de ejemplo, pon las que consideres oportunas.